# Cocoa app tries to launch lldb on crash?

Tags: macos, cocoa, debugging, osx-mavericks, lldb

A couple of users are reporting that sometimes when my app crashes, the receive a message box like this:

```
The lldb command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?
```

The crash (SIGABRT) looks like a race condition somewhere in my code. But why is it seemingly trying to launch `lldb` when this happens? I've never seen anything like this, it seems fairly isolated to a couple of users, and I can't reproduce locally - although I do have the developer tools installed.

It's almost like JIT debugging in a .NET, but I've never heard of that in Cocoa and my Google searches on this are fruitless.

---

Edit:

If I run `ps` we can see both the `Problem Reporter` and `Install Command Line Developer Tools`:

```
19582   0.0  0.4  2568032  33224   ??  S    10:22AM   0:00.72 /System/Library/CoreServices/Problem Reporter.app/Contents/MacOS/Problem Reporter
19579   0.0  0.2  2531748  13276   ??  S    10:22AM   0:00.16 /System/Library/CoreServices/Install Command Line Developer Tools.app/Contents/MacOS/Install Command Line Developer Tools
```

There is nothing else suspicious in the list. If I run `ps` with the `-f` switch, I can see that the parent process for `Install Command Line Developer Tools` is `launchd`.

Answer (score 2):

The CrashReporter tool that Apple ships does not try to connect a debugger to crashed programs.  There used to be an option to do that in Leopard or thereabouts (not on by default), but that capability was turned off by Mountain Lion (maybe even SnowLeopard).  I don't think it is possible to install any Xcode with lldb in it on Leopard, so it seems unlikely it is an old Apple CrashReporter that is trying to hook the debugger up to the app.  OTOH, it is possible to replace the Apple's CrashReporter tool with another that could do this, and some third party vendors do do this.  Maybe that is what is going on?

If you got the users who see this to send you the output of "ps auwwx" when the dialog box is present, you might be able to spot the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's very interesting. I'm going to try and get the output of the running processes...

Comment: I edited in this information. It seems to be the standard Apple problem reporter causing this. I did references to some tools that modify the problem reporter at runtime, but nothing that runs on an OS as new as 10.9...

Comment: I don't see at a quick glance how this could happen on 10.9.  This is curious, and it is definitely worth filing a bug about it.

Comment: I have open a support incident with Apple